# Reroute IP Traffic to another IP?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ip, route

Is it possible to reroute traffic from one IP/PORT to another in Server 2008? We host game servers, and I was tinkering with the idea of offering our clients an extra IP address, but reroute the connections to the IP that their server is actually running on.

Would something like this be possible?

Comment: If you're offering the clients an extra IP why not simply configure the additional address(es) on their machine and let them do what they want with it?

Comment: Because these aren't there machines. They pay to have the game server hosted on one of our machines, so they technically only get the 1 IP address/Port combination with the rental of their service.

Comment: OK but the same principle applies: Just bind their server(software) to both IPs -- Likely to be less mess than rigging up forwarding services...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably port forwarding which can be accomplished using the "netsh interface portproxy" command in Windows Server 2008.

A blogpost with an example [can be found here](http://www.rickwargo.com/2011/01/08/port-forwarding-port-mapping-on-windows-server-2008-r2/), further information on the netsh interface portproxy command is part of the [Windows Server documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc776297%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

In most circumstances (not all), IP/port forwarding is handled by the firewall, unless you're using [RRAS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb545655?ppud=4)...